# Using multiple DTDs (from mozilla.org)

Tags: xhtml, dtd

I need use XHTML.

In the URL https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/XUL/Using_multiple_DTDs (updated in Sept 9 2019) Mozilla say:

""" If you want to use multiple DTDs with your XUL file, you can simply list all of the DTDs inside your DTD declaration: """

```
<!DOCTYPE window [
  <!ENTITY % commonDTD SYSTEM "chrome://myextensions/locale/common.dtd">
  %commonDTD;
  <!ENTITY % mainwindowDTD SYSTEM "chrome://myextension/locale/mainwindow.dtd">
  %mainwindowDTD;
]>
```

but: how I can load the "official" www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd + MyOwn.tdt" ??

Logically this structure is wrong, but please: how I can fixed this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html[
<!ENTITY % commonDTD PUBLIC "chrome://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
%commonDTD;
<!ENTITY % qfc SYSTEM "chrome://myweb.com/DTD/my.dtd">
%qfc;
]>
```

I need load two DTD, one remote:
http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd
and other local:
mydtd.dtd

the first with "PUBLIC" and second with "SYSTEM".

However mozilla.org don't show a example to load one PUBLIC + other SYSTEM.

Thanks by your help.

Comment: Stupid question, but can't you include the official DTD inside your own DTD (at the top), so the doctype of the file only needs to reference your DTD.

Comment: the question is HOW do this?, how inlcude the remote DTD into my local DTD